# redirect all images links from others websites to a url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My hosted images are linked in other websites , so now i want redirect those link to my site.
my images link look like this
`http://example.com/uploads/images/September2014//iphone-6.gif`  (all image types jpg,gif,png etc)
**sepetember2014/**   is dynamic text that will change every month  (monthname(alphabets)Year(in digits))plus **extra /** on its end.
now i want above url redirect to

```
http://example.com/media/iphone-6
```

i try following but didint work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com
RewriteRule ^\.jpg $1\.html [R=301,L
```

my site htacess look like this 
after using anubhava answer

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com$
RewriteRule ^uploads/images/.+?/([^./]+)\.jpg$ /media/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: What is your server `example.com` OR `yourdomain.com`?

Comment: i fixed its example.com

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't seem correct. You can use this rule in as **first rule** in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com$
RewriteRule ^uploads/images/.+?/([^./]+)\.jpg$ /media/$1.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: it redirect perfectly  but then my images dont show up at all on my site

Comment: Even if you remove this rule and you enter `http://example.com/media/iphone-6` in your browser does it find your image?

Comment: New rule will only impact `http://example.com/uploads/images/September2014//iphone-6.gif` so even with nee rule `http://example.com/media/iphone-6` should work. Also seems like you have more rules in your .htaccess, if that's the case place this 301 rule as **first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line.